# Dart RegEx is not splitting String

Tags: regex, dart

Im a fresher to RegEx.
I want to get all Syllables out of my String using this RegEx:
`/[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*\$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?/gi`

And I implemented it in Dart like this:

```dart
void main() {
  String test = 'hairspray';
  final RegExp syllableRegex = RegExp("/[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*\$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?/gi");
  print(test.split(syllableRegex));
}
```

The Problem:
Im getting the the word in the List not being splitted.
What do I need to change to get the Words divided as List.

I tested the RegEx on regex101 and it shows up to Matches.
But when Im using it in Dart with `firstMatch` I get `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- Use a mere string pattern without regex delimiters in Dart as a regex pattern
- Flags are not used, `i` is implemented as a `caseSensitive` option to `RegExp` and `g` is implemented as a `RegExp#allMatches` method
- You need to *match and extract*, not *split* with your pattern.

You can use

```dart
String test = 'hairspray';
final RegExp syllableRegex = RegExp(r"[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?",
                caseSensitive: true);
for (Match match in syllableRegex.allMatches(test)) {
   print(match.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
hair
spray
```

Comment: Also likely want `$` instead of `\$` since the latter matches a literal `$`, not the end of input.

Comment: @lrn Right, in a regular string literal, it was escaped so as to be parsed as a literal `$` char.